# How to use a duplicate value in a Column to calculate the value of a second column in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table, from a product structure, with parent, child, level and quantity information.
I need to consolidade the component quantity per position on the structure.

I am able to build the StructurePath data using VBA in a single loop.

The main assumption is StructurePath shall be unique across the entire table.

Question:
Is there a procedure to look for all values in **StructurePath** and sum up the total **QTY-PER** value, generating a data line in the **Consolidated QTY** column? After that, I can simply eliminate duplicates using the StructurePath column.

[Exploded structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6iZ6.png)

Comment: Please show a mock-up of the data and the code you have currently generated, by editing your post.  This almost sounds like you're looking for a pivot table, given the written description... will need more detail to understand what is happening.  A for "a procedure", there are many that could be written, some using `sumproduct()` or other worksheet functions, or straight VBA.  It all depends on what you're building from.

Comment: There is an image of the data attached, but I don't know how to attach an excel file, sorry.
The pivot table does the trick indeed.
This is how it is done, manually then a Vlookup on the results back to the main table, then remove the duplicates.

I would like a straight VBA solution since I am trying to automate a painful, tedious process.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, since I'm limited in English, I can't understand this sentence :

> generating a data line in the Consolidated QTY column

Anyway, the code below will sum the value in column D (QTY-PER) based on each unique value of column H (StructurePath), and put the result in column F at the first row occurence of each unique value.

```
Sub test()

Set rg = Range("H2", Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each cell In rg: arr.Item(cell.Value) = 1: Next

    For Each el In arr
        Set c = rg.Find(el, After:=rg.Cells(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count), lookat:=xlWhole)
        c.Offset(0, -2).Value = Application.SumIf(rg, el, rg.Offset(0, -4))
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry karma. I am also not an english native speaker.... 
I was wondering to have the total qty for each STRUCT value, as you calculated indeed, repeated on every occurrence of the STRUCT, then remove duplicates. 

Your approach looks great. Then I just need to remove rows where QTY CON is empty.
I'll test it later.

Comment: @LuizNunes, I'm sorry because my code doesn't put the total value for each STRUCT in each row but to one "unique" STRUCT only. And you are correct, with my code, you just need to remove the rows where QTY CON is empty.